# Create a Javascript POPUP by using the address bar

Tags: javascript, firefox, popupwindow, address-bar

I trying to bookmark a popup window link as a popup window rather then just a normal bookmark link something like so:

```
javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com','popupwindow','width=753,height=617')
```

So when you put it in the address bar or as a bookmark it will open the link as a popup window. So far i manage to get it working but the current tab which i am on also get's loaded with this printed on the page:

```
[object Window]
```

Is there anyway to stop it from affecting the current page?

I'm trying to do this on `Mozilla Firefox.`

Comment: javascript:window.open(...);return false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap it in [`void()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.com','popupwindow','width=753,height=617'))
```

`window.open` returns a `Window` object.  That result is then being written to the page.  `void()` will mask the `Window` and return `undefined` instead, which the browser will not write to the page.